# EF Core saving my data with a foreign key different from the one I give it

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

This might be due to the fact that I misunderstand something in EF Core's functioning, I'm not an expert in it.

I have a user, and a user settings model. they have a one to one relationship configured as follows:

```
public class User : BaseEntity
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public UserSettings? UserSettings { get; set; }
}

public class UserSettings : BaseEntity
{
    public string PreferredLanguage { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public UserSettings()
    {
        User = new User();
        PreferredLanguage = string.Empty;
        UserId = string.Empty;
    }
}


modelBuilder.Entity<UserSettings>()
            .HasOne(us => us.User)
            .WithOne(u => u.UserSettings)
            .HasForeignKey<UserSettings>(us => us.UserId)
            .IsRequired();
```

When I save a user settings object to the database, I ensure its `UserId` property is set to the value of an existing user.

```
userSettings.UserId = user.Id;
_appDbContext.UserSettings.Add(userSettings);
            
var res = await _appDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

But after Entity Framework saves it, I try to retrieve the `usersettings` object, but its `UserId` property is different from the one I assigned to it before saving it.

To correct the issue, I assign the entire User object to the user setting's User property, instead of assigning only the userId `userSettings.User = user;` and it works.

My question is, why does it behave this way? Why is it that I must assign the whole User object to the user settings for EF Core to create a `Usersettings` object with the correct foreign key value?

Comment: What did you assign to `.User` ? And where did `userSettings` and `User` come from? You don't have to set the FK property if you already have a property for the entity itself. You don't have to call `Add` or `Update` for entities loaded by EF Core itself either. The DbContext will detect the objects have changed and save all of them when you call `SaveChanges`. `Add` is only needed to *attach* objects non-EF (detached) objects in the `Created` state. `Add` will attach any related detached objects too

Comment: `why does it behave this way` because the constructor *already* specified  the `User` property with `User = new User();`. That's a bug, unless you explicitly want every `UserSetting` instance to be associated with a new user object. Modifying the shadow FK property doesn't modify the actual, new object

Comment: **Never** initialize reference navigation properties with `new` - golden EF and EF Core rule.

Comment: 1. First Remove `new User()` from `UserSettings` constructor because it create a new User entity with default values 
2. Add a foreign key property to the `User` entity `public string UserSettingsId {get; set;}` for consistency
3. Then it will better to assign the settings to the user this way `user.UserSettings = userSettings` instead of `userSettings.UserId = user.Id;`

Comment: Thanks!! I didn't know about that. I'll apply what you just taught me.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you need to assign the whole User object to the UserSettings object is because the UserId property is a foreign key. A foreign key is a field in a table that refers to the primary key of another table. In this case, the UserId property in the UserSettings table refers to the Id property in the User table.

When you assign the UserId property to the value of an existing user, Entity Framework does not know which user you are referring to. It needs to know the entire user object in order to look up the correct user in the database.

If you assign the entire User object to the UserSettings object, Entity Framework will be able to look up the correct user in the database and set the UserId property to the correct value.

**Here is a simplified explanation of what happens when you save the UserSettings object:**

Entity Framework creates a new row in the UserSettings table.
Entity Framework sets the UserId property in the new row to the value of the Id property in the User object that you passed to the Add() method.
Entity Framework saves the new row to the database.
If you only assign the UserId property to the UserSettings object, Entity Framework will not be able to set the UserId property to the correct value because it does not know which user you are referring to.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the comments made on my question provided an answer. By the way, you're explaining to me the concept of foreign key, which I know, and I know why entity framework wants me to add a usersettings object. What I didn't know was why it created new users.